# reinstall PHP as apache module

Tags: apache-2.2, php

sorry for the newbie question, I am not a sys admin by any means.

I recently set up a VPS with webmin/virtualmin. Our CMS of choice says that PHP needs to be run as an Apache module in order to run. It says:

`Recompile PHP with the flag --with-apxs`

I've googled but can't find how to do this particularly. I think I installed PHP using "yum install php" or thru webmin, but can't remember exactly.

Appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably give a little more information in order to get the best answers; such as what OS/version do you have? What CMS?

Since you mention yum, I'm going to assume a redhat based system, such as CentOS. If you have installed php using yum and you have apache installed, have you actually started apache? ('service httpd start'). Perhaps (at least that part of) your CMS installation just works?

If not, tell us what happens.
Tell us what you have, what you did and what response you got.

Answer (score 0):

"As an Apache module" means using mod_php, rather than php-cgi.  I believe the php package on CentOS includes that.